# query to fetch records between two date and time

Tags: postgresql

I have been using postgreSQL. My table has 3 columns date, time and userId. I have to find out records between the given date and time frame. Since date and time columns are different, 'BETWEEN' clause is not providing valid results

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have tried so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two columns into a single timestamp by adding the time to the date:

```
select *
from some_table
where date_column + time_column 
         between timestamp '2017-06-14 17:30:00' and timestamp '2017-06-19 08:26:00';
```

Note that this will not use an index on `date_column` or `time_column`. You would need to create an index on that expression. Or better: use a single column defined as `timestamp` instead.

Comment: @YogeshSingh: if it works, then please accept the answer, so that your question is marked as resolved.